# Favourite questions and answers from the 3rd quarter of 2018

Tags: discussion, answers, questions

End of third quarter and we return to ask you about your favorite questions and answers. So, what are your favorite questions and answers from **1st July 2018 to 30th September 2018**.

You can use search to find all the eligible [questions](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+created%3A2018-07..2018-09) and [answers](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+created%3A2018-07..2018-09) posted in the past quarter. Since we got 501 questions and 760 answers in the past quarter. Here are some data queries to help with the decision making process.

- [Questions with the most number of votes from the third quarter](https://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/738289/questions-with-best-score-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2018/07/01)
- [Questions with the most number of views from the third quarter](https://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/738288/questions-with-most-views-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2018/07/01)
- [Answers with most number of votes from the third quarter](https://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/738290/answers-with-best-score-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2018/07/01)

The above questions and answers are only for your hint. Feel free to mention any question or answer you enjoyed writing. Since this is not a competition, there's no need to mention one question or answer per one answer. Also don't hesitate to mention our own questions and answers which you think didn't get the appreciation they deserved.

Answer (score 9):

Some I enjoyed for the research that went into the Q&A pairs

Q: [Why does Firefly include a scene with a missing yoke?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/90100/why-does-firefly-include-a-scene-with-a-missing-yoke)

Although the primary answer was found elsewhere, Tejusin's [analytical answer.](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/90102/34317) was excellent.

Q: [How far did Forrest Gump run?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/92091/how-far-did-forrest-gump-run)

Mouvier' provided a [detailed answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/92092/34317)

Comment: I really liked the Forrest Gump question too, and the answer by Mouvier as well.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I was particularly moved by [*sanpaco*'s answer to my question about *The Way Back*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/92170/49).

I asked that question more than 3.5 years ago. I already half-answered it in the question and wasn't sure if there will even be more insights to this, especially since it stayed unanswered for so long (and at one point even ended up auto-deleted for inactivity).

But after all this time it doesn't only get an answer but even more so an answer that provides new insights I didn't actually consider before. It's not only a testimony for the beauty of this site and its contribution to appreciating films an TV-shows as every good answer and question is, but also a statement for patience and the fact that no question is ever too old to get a good answer.

<sub>And it ties in well to the background of the film itself, which to my opinion is very underrated and has gone quite unnoticed in the broader public while being an excellent film, one which I only happened to catch on TV by accident, too.</sub>